# Slim tag inside another tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, slim-lang

I'm looking for cleaner solution, more Slim  like, to write tag inside tag, this is what I have so far:

```
td = "#{p.created_at.to_formatted_s(:long)} <small>(#{time_ago_in_words(p.created_at)} ago)</small>".html_safe
```

Code above works fine - generate output I want, but doesn't look clean for me. I've tried rewrite it to eRuby

```
<td><%= p.created_at.to_formatted_s(:long) %> <small><%= time_ago_in_words(p.created_at) %> ago)</small></td>
```

And then convert it to Slim using [Erb2Slim](http://erb2slim.herokuapp.com) converter

```
td
  = p.created_at.to_formatted_s(:long)
    small
     = time_ago_in_words(p.created_at)
     | ago)
```

After that it doesn't show `small` tag and its content, **any idea how and what is the best way to write above code in Slim?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you have a problem with indents (spaces). Try to use the following indents:

```
  td
    = p.created_at.to_formatted_s(:long)
    |  
    small
      | (
      = time_ago_in_words(p.created_at)
      | ago)
```

Note: in 3rd line 2 spaces needed after the pipe

Comment: Thanks! It works with small tweaks, but to achieve exactly the same effect, like on the first listing, Slim code looks like pure madness...